# Conditional AFTER DELETE trigger and ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I have a trigger for each table that depending on the value of a column (`id_op` to be more precise) makes an insert in another table, something like this (example from `entity` table):

```
CREATE TRIGGER entity_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON entity
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN old.id_op IS NULL OR old.id_op <> -2
BEGIN
    -- insert some info into another table
END
```

There are other tables that reference `entity` through an FK and all have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` for this. This means that if I perform a `DELETE FROM entity`, all tables referencing `entity` will cascade this delete and execute the `AFTER DELETE` trigger as well. My problem is I cannot control these triggers from a cascade in this case.

The obvious solution is to first properly update all rows in tables referencing this one, but this looks like a too expensive solution. Does anyone have a better idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.